# before, beforeEach, after, and afterEach of mocha equivalent in pytest

Tags: pytest

I'm new to python and using pytest along with requests to start API testing.

I want to run some scripts before each test module and other snippets before each test case in a module for testcases data setup.

I've checked pytest fixtures and scope but I don't think this is what I'm looking for as I can't control the data passed to fixtures. What other possible solutions for that?

Comment: Fixtures _are_ the way to do this in pytest. Maybe you are looking for [parametrized fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/fixtures.html#parametrizing-fixtures)?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen
I did use parametrized fixtures to generate auth tokens whenever I need, but I have to call it with each test function. 

I'm looking for something to make it called once per module or only for a group of tests per module.

Comment: If you don't need to access the fixture directly, you can set it to `autouse=True`, if you _do_ need to access it in the test however, you indeed have to pass it as an argument.